# Javascript Access an an Object in an Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm fetching data from MongoDB, and the response is coming through fine, however it appears to be wrapped in array when it comes out of the User.find() function.

For example, one response is:

```
[{"_id":"62fe3c888e2776ef3c1a010f","username":"Drago D Trial","password":"U2FsdGVkX1867hs26KL0KitTGhWnP9tdVX6AcmI5pWE=","fullname":"Drago DaTrial","firstname":"","surname":"","email":"drago@hotmail.com","position":"QA Tester","userImage":"","locationCity":"","country":"","role":"","company":"","emailAuthorised":true,"professionalBio":"","positionRecentTitle":"","positionRecentCompany":"","companyAuthorised":"","isAdmin":false,"createdAt":"2022-08-18T13:20:08.045Z","updatedAt":"2022-08-18T13:21:02.619Z","__v":0}]
```

I'm accessing this through an api like this:

```
router.get('/inviteToJoinTeam/:token/:email', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      //verify the token against DB
      const userToken = (req.params.token)
      const indivEmailAdd = (req.params.email)

      // creating user auth
      try{
        const userDetails = await User.find({email: indivEmailAdd})
        const indivIDAdd = await userDetails (!want to access the data here and just get ID)

        res.send(indivIDAdd)


      }catch{
        console.log('failure')
      }

 
    } catch (e) {
      res.send('This isnt working');
    }
  
  });
```

How would you access this and just get the _id field out?

Comment: If you just need a single entry use the `findOne` method instead of `find`.

Comment: `User.find()` always returns an array. To get only the field(s) from the resulting documents, use _projection_ in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one item in the array then - simply get the id property of the first item intthe returned array

```
const indivIDAdd = await userDetails[0]['_id'];
```

or using dot notation

```
 const indivIDAdd = await userDetails[0]._id;
```

if there are multiple results then map over the results and get the id from each

```
const ids = await userDetails.map(user => user._id);
```

Answer (score 1):

just use response[0]._id

Ps: Response is the array coming from the database

Answer (score 1):

Try projection for the same it should work

```
const userDetails = await User.find({ email: indivEmailAdd }, { _id : 1 })
```

it will return array of ObjectId. if you need to get only one object then use `findOne` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you have 2 solutions :

Option 1 use `findOne` instead of `find` :

```
const userDetails = await User.findOne({email: indivEmailAdd});
```

Option 2 access array / object with basic js:

```
const usersDetails = await User.find({email: indivEmailAdd});
const userDetails = usersDetails.at(0)._id; // or
const userDetails = usersDetails[0]['_id'];
```